# WordPress admin panel redirect and none solution works

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu

What I did:

I had two wordpress websites on two different machines running (Ubuntu 18.04) and I wanted to move one website to the other machine that both run on one server. So I followed these steps:

1) Copied the whole wordpress folder to the other machine (apache root with new subfolder)
2) Edited the wp-config.php
3) Created a backup of the mysql database (whole database)
4) Created a new mysql database on the other machine
5) Created a new database user for the new database with all privileges on it 6) Imported all the data from the mysql backup to the new database

Thats roughly all what I did. Also I created a certificate with lets encrypt on the old machine and https worked fine with my website.

What I tried to solve the problem:

1) Cleared all website data 2) Added the correct site url in wp-config for "WP_HOME" and "WP_SITEURL" 3) deactivated all plugins and themes 4) Deleted .htaccess file 5) Created new default .htaccess file 6) set "FORCE_SSL_ADMIN" to true 7) restart apache and mysql service

Sadly none solution mentioned above worked. I searched the web for many hours but I couldn't find any other possible solution. I don't know what I did wrong. :/

Comment: did you change the user or password in wp-config.php? did you change the URL? Are the siteurl and home settings properly set in the table wp_options? Did you check your debug files?

Comment: @Cerveser I changed the user and password and also set the site url and home properly. What do you mean with change url? In the Dashboard? If I set the site url and home you can't change the url in the dashboard anymore. How to check the debug files?

Comment: is the URL changed for the website? If so you need to change the siteurl and home settings in the MySQL table wp_options, for debugging: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress